# Rendering head section meta tags in a custom PHP CMS

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, seo, html-title

(I'm a complete novice programmer)

I recently came across a problem with my custom CMS. I want to make it SEO friendly so I tried to echo out the title by the page loaded e.g.

`www.blaa.com/index.php?page=about
//code here grabs the required page title from the mysql db $title = $row['title'];
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>`

I can't see if this actually worked because when I view source it only displays this code:

`<table>
<tr><td>Custom Module<br><br>`

My custommodule cus any html goes in here

`</td></tr>
<tr><td>Menu Body <br><br>
<a href='home.html'> home</a><br><a href='about page.html'> about page</a><br><br><br> </td></tr>
<tr><td>body<br>
cant believe im so a<br></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Footer<br>
links go here to various pages<br></td></tr>
</table>`

Is there a way to make all of the HTML code display in the view source?

Comment: you question makes no sense without any actual code. And view-source does display full HTML code, it doesn't hide it. Maybe you have some errors.

Comment: View source will show the source as received from the webserver unless you are using any kind of frames in which case view source may only show the selected frame's source.

Comment: sorry guys i did put it in must made a mistake with the indent stuff heres the code: <table>

<tr><td>Custom Module<br><br>



My custommodule cus any html goes in here<br><br>



</td></tr>
<tr><td>Menu Body <br><br>
<a href='home.html'> home</a><br><a href='about page.html'> about page</a><br><a href='sian jus pooped.html'> sian jus pooped</a><br><a href='products.html'> products</a><br><br><br> </td></tr>

<tr><td>body<br>
</table>

Comment: the above is the code that its displayed when i go to www.bllaa.com?page=about. When i just go to the index.php page it does display all of the source code. What I've done is this:   //grab title from mysql db... <title><?php echo $title; ?> ... i cant see if it worked because it does not display in the custom pages view source

Comment: @saintybalboa - just so you know, it is a good idea to take some time to ensure that questions (on any forum like this) are well formatted and readable - your code didn't show up, as you didn't close the code formatting marks. It's generally better to use `<pre>` or four-space indents for code anyway, rather than inline code formatting. Have a quick read of the `Markdown` help if you get a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `echo` or `print` a variable to show it. You could also do a `var_dump` to check what the values are.

```
<?php
$title = isset($_GET['title'])? $_GET['title'] : "No title.";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?></title>
</head>
```

I added `htmlspecialchars` to prevent script injection, I don't know if it would work in the `title` tag but I added it just in case. Plus you should know whenever you write user input into your HTML page you should use htmlspecialchars to cancel out any html code & scripts.

If your custom module is a load of HTML you wanted to display, you should use the `inlude` command:

```
<body>
<?php include("path/to/custom_module.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>

# custom_module.php
<div>Hello, I'm the custom module.</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I have done this with my code. The problem is when I go to view source on one of the custom pages e.g. about it only displays a small snippet of code and not the whole html <head><title></title> etc so I dont know if it worked.

Comment: That means the variable was null or unset. You probably have PHP errors turned off so it continues silently. Rather than develop on your webserver you should download PHP 5.4 windows binary, it comes with a development server ready to use (no install required). Then you can use an IDE like Eclipse or Aptana to develop on your desktop, and check the page on your computer rather than your server. That way you can have all errors turned on and debug your problems.

Comment: Sorry guys I was testing this only local host. Now I've tested it online it does actually work sorry for messing about, really appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: http://windows.php.net/download/ <-- go here and download the Non-Thread-Safe zip, unzip it to C:/php, then in cmd.exe run these operations: `cd C:/php` then `php -S localhost:8888 -t c:/myserver/` then the server will start on your PC. Go to your browser and type `localhost:8888/` if you have an `index.php` file in `c:/myserver` it will run PHP code off there.